# Loading a child-theme's style.css after the parent's

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to load my child theme's `style.css` after the parent theme `style.css` has already loaded. However, I have noticed that the `style.css` doesn't need to be enqueued since it's implicitly enqueued by the WordPress core.

So I'm explicitly enqueuing it like this, where it is dependent on the `parent-style` having already loaded:

```
function enqueue_theme_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/style.css', array('parent-style') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

The problem with this is that it's now **loaded twice**. Once implicitly and then explicitly. How can I load my child's `style.css` after the parent's without loading it twice?

Here's what the `head` looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
    <?php if(isset($themeum['favicon'])){ ?>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $themeum['favicon']; ?>" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/plus.png' ?>" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <?php } ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">

    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php if(isset($themeum['before_head'])) echo $themeum['before_head'];?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: WordPress doesn't load style.css so I think the parent theme is. Can you paste your header.php form your theme? And from functions.php in the parent, any code hooking a style sheet in?

Comment: Which one of the styles is loaded twice?

Comment: @MaxYudin, he meant child theme's `style.css`.

Comment: @bravokeyl hmm. Now I reread the question that sounds right. Maybe the parent theme references stylesheet directory rather than template directory. Hard to help without seeing.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook, you are absolutely correct. I guess parent theme might be loading it ( for example: `Genesis` does)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Andy Macaulay-Brook pointed out WordPress doesn't load `child-theme's` **`style.css`** . I guess parent theme might be en-queuing it.

- De-queue the child-theme `style.css` first and then enqueue it
- En-queue **parent's** style.css before  **child theme's** style.css

### De-queue the child-theme `style.css`

You can de-queue the child-theme's style.css by using the handle.You can find out the handle either by looking at the parent theme (assuming it's being loaded from it) or by looking at the link of the page source.

For example:

Link from the site using `Twenty Fifteen theme` looks like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfifteen-style-css'  href='http://wp.dev/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css?ver=4.5.3-alpha-37528' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

For which the handle is `twentyfifteen-style` which is the **id** of the link tag but without `-css`.

So we can de-queue this using [`wp_dequeue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) hooking to [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/)

```
wp_dequeue_style('twentyfifteen-style');
```

### En-queue **parent's** style.css before  **child theme's** style.css (depends on list of dependencies)

By changing the priority of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook less than default (10) and loading the parent theme `style.css`. (I'm unsure of this have to check)

```
function wpse_227769_enqueue_scripts() {
   //Load parent theme style.css here
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_227769_enqueue_scripts', 9 );
```

Comment: Cool. I hadn't noticed the handle was used as an ID. Handy.

Comment: That was very helpful! That should do it. :) Thanks!

Comment: I think the priorities on this hook get overridden by the arrays of dependencies. Safer to list the dependencies to get the ordering that you want.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook, yes , got it, had a little bit of doubt on this before just checked `functions.wp-styles.php` and `class-wp-dependencies` class.

Comment: I found that it was being loaded in the parent's functions.php by `        wp_enqueue_style('thm-style',get_stylesheet_uri());`.